# Mixin question for ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm overriding a ModelAdmin method thus:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    # alter redirect location if 'source' is found in GET
    response = super(JobOptions, self).response_change(request, obj)
    source = request.GET.get('source', None)
    if source:
        response['location'] = source
    return response
```

Rather than repeat this on every model I'd like to make it a mixin.

If I do:

```
def RedirectMixin(admin.ModelAdmin)
```

and then:

```
def MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin, RedirectMixin)
```

then I get a MRO error.

However if RedirectMixin doesn't inherit from admin.ModelAdmin then the method doesn't get called.

An additional problem is how to generalise the super() call so it doesn't have the superclass hard-coded in.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, I presume you mean `class` rather than `def` in your examples.

Anyway, the right way to use a Mixin is to use it first in the list of classes to inherit. So:

```
class RedirectMixin(object):
```

and

```
class MyModelAdmin(RedirectMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
```

This is because Python looks through all parent classes *in order of declaration* to find the method, and calls the first one it finds.

As for super, this shouldn't be mentioning the superclass at all - that's the whole point of it. It should reference the current class:

```
return super(MyModelAdmin, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

or whatever.

**Edit after comments** Yes, the mixin should refer to its own class in the `super` call. Consider the following:

```
In [1]: class BaseClass(object):
   ...:     def my_function(self):
   ...:         print 'base my_function'
   ...:     

In [2]: class Mixin(object):
   ...:     def my_function(self):
   ...:         print 'mixin my_function'
   ...:         super(Mixin, self).my_function()
   ...: 

In [3]: class MyDerivedClass(Mixin, BaseClass):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
```

Now if you instantiate the subclass and call its `my_function` method, the MRO will happen as you expect, even though Mixin doesn't inherit from BaseClass:

```
In [4]: m=MyDerivedClass()

In [5]: m.my_function()
mixin my_function
base my_function
```

The error you mention comes if you fail to make `Mixin` a descendant of `object` - if you don't, it's an old-style class, which doesn't support the use of super.

Comment: Yes I did mean class instead of def :)

Comment: I'm confused by your comment about super(). the super call lives in the mixin class. Should it refer to the mixin classname? I get this error when I try that: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj